# Issue of memory exceed when update array values in loop in php

Tags: php, loops, memory-leaks, variable-declaration

The situation is that I have an array of 15000 records and each record have 67 key-value paired values. Now I want to update all values with using trim, str_replace or type-cast, but I get an error of php memory leak. I don't understand why this is happening. My array format is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 1
            [login] => 123
            [login_nickname] => 
            [password] => 123
            [subuser] => 0
            [subuser_id] => 
            [email] => usersemail@email.com
        ),
       [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 1
            [login] => 123
            [login_nickname] => 
            [password] => 123
            [subuser] => 0
            [subuser_id] => 
            [email] => anotheruser@email.com
        )
)
```

In this array I have some fields like comments, address and I want them trim, str_replace, some fields like branches(array) I want to type-cast it in object. But When I do then I get an error of memory exceed like this

**Fatel error:** Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted(tried to allocate 49 bytes) in **var/www/html/myproject/application/models/Member.php** on line **28**

**FYI:** When I echo these values in loop with using these functions(trim,str_replace,type-cast etc.) then loop is working fine and printing its value successfully.

I don't understand what is the problem , please help me.

My foreach loop is something like this

```
foreach($member_list as $index=>$member){
   foreach($member as $key=>$value){
      $member_list[$index][$key] = str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"), " ", trim($value));
   }
}
```

This error is occur in this loop.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: did it come from a db? chunk it up

Comment: You can use memory_get_usage to see how your usage proceeds as you build the array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

Comment: @Dagon, Yes this array is come from database but in this question I just show the format of my array.

Comment: @Barmar, I add a part of of my code

Answer (score -1):

This problem is basically related to PHP script consuming a lot of memory. In your case, as the amount of data is too large, even the 504 gateway timeout issue will start coming up pretty frequently. You should either use batch-processing(background processing) technique or execute your script using CLI or curl. These two techniques are well proven methodologies in the world of PHP to handle large running jobs.

Comment: Could you provide me any example that solves my purpose?

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that str_replace is actually quite an expensive method to use. If you profile your code (using a tool like xhprof (http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof), you'll see how expensive this method really is in terms of PHP CPU usage. To top it off (and I think this is your real problem), as you're looping through and assigning values, you are doubling up on memory, which is where you most likely into a problem (an issue you don't see when echoing the values).

If you still need to run the loop like this, increase your memory limit. You can do this either in your php.ini file (and then restart Apache) or at the beginning of your script, place the following code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M')
```

This will increase the memory available to PHP to 256MB. You may need to add more, but eventually, you'll have enough to be able to process the entire array.

On another note, consider fixing the data that goes into your DB, unless, of course, you're doing this just for a specific purpose.

*---Just to update this with examples of memory usage---*

EXAMPLE 1:

Running the following code on http://sb.meezaan.net/so/32195660/t1.php uses circa 43,000 bytes.

```
<?php
$x = [];
// create array.
$i = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++) {
    $x[$i]['id'] = $i;
    $x[$i]['name'] = rand(10909090,999999999999999);
    $x[$i]['time'] = time();
    $x[$i]['readable'] = date('r', time()); 
}

$start = memory_get_usage();
foreach ($x as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $key => $val) {
        $x[$k][$key] = str_replace(1,2, $val);
    }
}
$end = memory_get_usage();
$used = $end - $start;

var_dump('Memory consumed: ' . $used);
```

EXAMPLE 2:

Running the following code on http://sb.meezaan.net/so/32195660/t2.php uses circa 770 bytes (scroll to the bottom to see result).

```
<?php
$x = [];
// create array.
$i = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++) {
    $x[$i]['id'] = $i;
    $x[$i]['name'] = rand(10909090,999999999999999);
    $x[$i]['time'] = time();
    $x[$i]['readable'] = date('r', time()); 
}

$start = memory_get_usage();
foreach ($x as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $key => $val) {
        echo str_replace(1,2, $val) . '<br />';
    }
    echo '---<br />';
}
$end = memory_get_usage();
$used = $end - $start;

var_dump('Memory consumed: ' .  $used);
```

Comment: Why would it double up on memory? Each time he replaces a string, the old string becomes garbage and its memory should be reclaimed. PHP uses copy-on-write, so assigning variables doesn't make a copy unless you modify one of them.

Comment: I'm not sure about how the C code behind PHP works, but in my experience, the memory is only going to be reclaimed once the script is terminated. He's running out of memory when he assigns to variable - he doesn't when he echoes - that means he's consuming memory. The problem is quite simple. I will try and run some tests and see if I can produce some stats.

Comment: See http://sb.meezaan.me/so/32195660/t2.php and http://sb.meezaan.me/so/32195660/t2.txt for the code when echoing. Look for memory usage at the end of the dump. See http://sb.meezaan.me/so/32195660/t1.php and http://sb.meezaan.me/so/32195660/t1.txt for a comparison when assigning values. The t1 example has MUCH higher memory usage, over 55 times.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php for details of PHP garbage collection.

Comment: Will do. However, the proof is in the pudding (or example, as above).